# How can I upload files to my S3 bucket from my React app without a backend?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am creating a web app using React where the user can upload files to a folder in my S3 bucket. This folder will have a unique passcode name. The user (or someone else) can use this passcode to retrieve these files from the S3 folder. So basically there is no login/authentication system.

My current issue is how do I safely allow read/write access to my S3 bucket? Almost every tutorial stores the access keys to the client code which I read is very bad practice but I also don't want to create a backend for something this simple. Someone suggested presigned URLs but I have no idea how to set that up (do I use Lambda? IAMs?). I'm really new to AWS (and webdev in general). Does anyone have any pointers on what I could look into?

Comment: What does it mean "This folder will have a unique passcode name."? Buckets don't have passwords. And others are correct. To do it properly, you need backend.

Comment: Hi @Marcin, the folder will have a unique name like "6489125" so that the user can later type that into the UI and retrieve the files stored in that location

Comment: You really do want an authentication mechanism. Otherwise, you would need to make your S3 bucket "publicly uploadable", where anybody can upload whatever they want to your bucket. And, for the second part where they can access files that were previously uploaded, you'll need to make your bucket "publicly readable" so anybody can access the files. The result is that people will come and store pirated movies in your bucket and you will get hit with lots of Data Transfer costs for all of the traffic. Probably not something you'd like happening. You _could_ use AWS Lambda as your 'backend'.

Answer (score 0):

> do I use Lambda? IAMs?

The setup and process if fully explained in **AWS blog**:

- [Uploading to Amazon S3 directly from a web or mobile application](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/uploading-to-amazon-s3-directly-from-a-web-or-mobile-application/)